# How can I get iTunes to use iTunes Store Album Art?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, album-art

Some of my music in iTunes won't get Album Art via **"Get Album Art"**.  (These might be tracks from physical CDs, or that I've purchased a long time ago from other MP3 stores.)  I'd like to use the iTunes Store's Album Art whenever possible, because when it exists, it's usually a better quality image than from those from web searches.

What do I have to do to my tracks to get the iTunes Album Art?  What properties of a track does iTunes use when matching Album Art?

Comment: I would suggest finding the album on iTunes and seeing which parts of the metadata don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do in this situation is look up the album in the iTunes Store.

1. If it’s not available in the iTunes Store, I get the album art from some other source.
2. If it *is* available in the iTunes Store but “Get Album Art” doesn’t seem to do anything, there’s probably a mismatch in the meta data somewhere. Compare the Artist, Album Artist, and Album fields and make sure the fields in your local copy match those from the iTunes Store. Then try again.

This should take care of it in most cases. If that still doesn’t work, [try adding a space after the album title and/or the artist name](https://discussions.apple.com/message/6705256#6705256).